# Android fragment transition with shared element

Tags: android, android-fragments, transition, shared-element-transition

everyone!
I have 2 fragments. In one fragment i have a little image in card. In 2d fragment i have the same image in the header of my layout. I want to make shared element transition of this image from one fragment to another like in this example http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-Vv4SxVSI2DY/VEqQxAf3PWI/AAAAAAAAA7c/mfq7XBrIGgo/s1600/activity_transitions%2B(1).gif

2d fragment:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#f2f4f7">
<CustomScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#f2f4f7">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_wrapper"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:divider="@drawable/vertical_divider"
        android:showDividers="middle">
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/header_wrapper"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="166.7dp">
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/share_image"
                    android:transitionName="imageTransition"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="166.7dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/friday"/>
```

1st fragment:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
android:background="#ff1e1e23">
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:src="@drawable/menuicon1g"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textSize="22sp"/>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#fff"
    card_view:cardElevation="2dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/share_image"
            android:transitionName="imageTransition"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="92.5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/friday"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/demo_calendar"/>
        <com.zagum.work.virtualfitness.CustomTextView
            xmlns:com.zagum.work.virtualfitness="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.zagum.work.virtualfitness"
            android:id="@+id/date"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            com.zagum.work.virtualfitness:typeface="fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingLeft="40dp"
            android:paddingRight="40dp"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Transaction:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                View image = mRootView.findViewById(R.id.share_image);

                CurrentWorkoutFragment secondFragment = CurrentWorkoutFragment.newInstance();
                secondFragment.setSharedElementEnterTransition(TransitionInflater.from(getActivity()).inflateTransition(R.transition.transition_move));

                FragmentTransaction trans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                trans.replace(R.id.container, secondFragment);
                trans.addToBackStack(null);
                trans.addSharedElement(image, image.getTransitionName());
                trans.commit();
            }
```

transition_move.xml

```
<transitionSet xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <changeImageTransform />
   <changeBounds/>
</transitionSet>
```

But no image animation happens. It appears in the top left corner an resizes.

Comment: That animation is interesting. I'd say if you use a a list of fragments, when you click a fragment it starts and animation to take up the full screen. All the extra views are already in the fragment but they're hidden do to some sort of flags changing

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27214308/3718235) answer.

> Because the view I'm sharing between 2 fragments is a child of another
>   view (RelativeLayout) in the 2nd fragment, you need to add the
>   ChangeTransform transition to your TransitionSet.

Basically what you need is to add a `<changeTransform/>` in your transition_move.xml