# NavigationComponent recyclerview return shared element transition

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, shared-element-transition, android-architecture-navigation

I use Navigation Component in project. Trying to set up shared element transitions from recycler. And enter transition in the second fragment works fine, but when I return to the first fragment - there is no return transition.

I tried to explicitly set enter and return transitions in the first fragment like I did in the second like this

```
val transition = TransitionInflater.from(context).inflateTransition(android.R.transition.move)

sharedElementEnterTransition = transition

sharedElementReturnTransition = transition
```

but it didn't help.

Also tried to remove enter and exit fragment animations. For the second fragment enter transition works with animations, but who knows.

also tried to use the solution from this question, but in my case it didn't work.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52922835/10951565

mainFragment

```
stickyAdapter.onItemClick = { event, imageView, textView ->
            val args = bundleOf(EventDetailFragment.EVENT to event)
            val extras = FragmentNavigatorExtras(
                imageView to imageView.transitionName,
                textView to textView.transitionName
            )
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_global_eventDetailFragment, args, null, extras)
        }
```

in adapter onClick I set unique transition names for the views:
mainFragmentAdapter

```
eventImageView.setOnClickListener {
            titleTextView.transitionName = "${event.title}$TRANSITION_TITLE"
            eventImageView.transitionName = "${event.title}$TRANSITION_IMAGE" 
            onItemClick?.invoke(event, eventImageView, titleTextView) 
        }
```

in detailsFragment I get transition names from arguments (copypasted them to be sure there is no mistakes and for enter transition it worked)
I call postponeEnterTransition() in OnCreate method to wait until i can set transition names, sharedElementEnterTransition and sharedElementReturnTransition in onViewCreated and then call startPostponedEnterTransition()

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        postponeEnterTransition()
    }

override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_event_detail, container, false).apply {
        val event = arguments?.getSerializable(EVENT) as Event?
        toolbarImageView.transitionName = "${event?.title}$TRANSITION_IMAGE"
        titleTextView.transitionName = "${event?.title}$TRANSITION_TITLE"

        val transition = TransitionInflater.from(context).inflateTransition(android.R.transition.move)
        sharedElementEnterTransition = transition
        sharedElementReturnTransition = transition
        startPostponedEnterTransition()

        toolbar.setupWithNavController(findNavController())

        event?.let {
            Picasso.get()
                .load("${EventGroupAdapter.BASE_SMALL_IMAGE_URL}${event.smallimage}")
                .into(toolbarImageView)
        }
    }
}
```

main_fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".view.activity.MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="256dp"
        android:background="?android:colorBackground"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

                <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" />

                <com.rd.PageIndicatorView
                    android:id="@+id/pageIndicatorView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/viewPager"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
                    app:piv_dynamicCount="true"
                    app:piv_interactiveAnimation="true"
                    app:piv_radius="3.5dp"
                    app:piv_selectedColor="@color/colorIndicatorSelected"
                    app:piv_unselectedColor="@color/colorIndicatorUnselected"
                    app:piv_viewPager="@id/viewPager" />

                <include
                    android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
                    layout="@layout/fragment_main_horizontal_scroll_view"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/viewPager" />

            </RelativeLayout>

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/emptyMessage"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layoutAnimation="@anim/layout_animation_from_bottom"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_empty_events"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/empty_events_message"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"

                tools:listitem="@layout/fragment_main_event_item" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/programTextView"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone"
        tools:visibility="visible" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="?android:colorBackground"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Please share your recipe of the return shared element transition with Navigation Component

Comment: You can check my answer to this problem on this link [Link to the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56378178/11578100)!

Comment: here is another answer to this problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/56956248/2339405

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ran into this the other day where going from the `MainFragment` item to a `DetailFragment` animated fine, but the `sharedElementReturnTransition` wasn't working when pressing back.

The fix for me was to postpone the transition on the `MainFragment`. At first, I was trying to do so in `onCreate`, but `onCreate` isn't always called when going back, so the fix was to postpone it in `onViewCreated` (I would guess `onCreateView` might work too) and then start the transition once the `RecyclerView` is ready.

DetailFragment:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    val transition = TransitionInflater.from(context).inflateTransition(android.R.transition.move)
    sharedElementEnterTransition = transition
    sharedElementReturnTransition = transition
}
```

MainFragment:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    postponeEnterTransition()
    recycler_view.post { startPostponedEnterTransition() }
}
```

Comment: I will mark this answer as accepted, but I can't check if it works or not. But looks like a working one